# Get UUID of linux in C#

Tags: c#, linux, shell

I am working on a C# application in .NET Core. My requirement is that i have to find the UUID of linux machine through C# code. The command which is used to find the UUID on linux is:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-uuid
```

The way i am using it in C# code is:

```
ProcessStartInfo proc_start_info = new ProcessStartInfo();
proc_start_info.FileName = "bash";
proc_start_info.Arguments = "-c dmidecode -s system-uuid";

proc_start_info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc_start_info.UseShellExecute = false;
proc_start_info.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = proc_start_info;
proc.Start();
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine("Obtained result : " + result);
```

Issue in the above code is that it prints all the information from **dmidecode** command but, i only want to print the UUID. I know, i can extract the UUID from the returned string but is there any other way in which i only get the UUID printed.

Comment: Can you use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iSMBIOS/) NuGet package?

Comment: Not sure, will look into it. BTW thanks for sharing this :) @jira